# Lightning component Slowness after Enable Lightning LockerService Security is turned On

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service, critical-update

I am using jstree (jQuery component) in one of my lightning component and i am experiencing unusual delay after turning on Lightning LockerService Security, this delay is noticeable in hover, scroll and click events on jstree nodes

Refer the screenshots

Before Enabling Lightning LockerService Security
[image]

After Enabling Lightning LockerService Security
[image]

Looks like h and l are the methods which are taking more time these methods are from aura component (aura_prod.js)

Answer (score 3):

Locker does introduce a small amount of overhead (reduced massively in the Winter'17 .11 patch) but it should typically not be significant. If you enable Lightning Components debug mode in Setup and grab a new set of profiles we'll get a much better set of symbols than the obfuscated h and l.

@Sachin I originally added this as comment on your post and did not here back - how are things looking with Spring'17 (we've continued to work on reducing the overhead of locker)? The next set of improvements have already been made in Summer'17 and are planned to be back ported to Spring'17 soon.

Comment: Hopefully this will help https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/why-its-time-to-break-up-with-javascript-buttons-and-embrace-lightning.html

Comment: Dough, is there a way I can contact you directly regarding a similar issue?